# Writing a query that contains variable WHERE based on user input

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having trouble with a query. What I would like it to do is check that each variable exists, and ignore them if they don't. I also want to display the results in a table. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What I have so far: This is my code. At the moment, it returns an array with all results from the database, but if I change the ORs in the WHERE clause to AND, all fields need to be filled. I want the user to be able to input as much information as they know, in order to display all possible results.

```
<?php require("common.php");?>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST))
{
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE First_name LIKE '%$First_name%' OR Surname LIKE '%$Surname%' OR DOB LIKE '$DOB' OR Street LIKE '%$Street%' OR Suburb LIKE '$Suburb' OR State LIKE '$State' OR Postcode LIKE '$Postcode' OR Phone LIKE '$Phone'");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);



$First_name = $_POST['First_name'];
$Surname = $_POST['Surname'];
$DOB = $_POST['DOB'];
$Street = $_POST['Street'];
$Suburb = $_POST['Suburb'];
$State = $_POST['State'];
$Postcode = $_POST['Postcode'];
$Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
}
?>
<fieldset><legend>Find a customer</legend>
<form name="querycustomerform" method="post" action="qcustomer.php">
    <table class="five">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <h3>Please fill out as many details as possible</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="First_name" maxlength="30" size="30" placeholder="First name">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Surname" maxlength="30" size="30" placeholder="Surname">
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: right">Date of Birth:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" name="DOB">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Street" maxlength="40" size="30" placeholder="Street Address">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Suburb" maxlength="15" size="30" placeholder="Suburb">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="State">
                <option value="">State</option>
                <option value="ACT">Australian Capital Territory</option>
                <option value="NSW">New South Wales</option>
                <option value="NT">Northern Territory</option>
                <option value="QLD">Queensland</option>
                <option value="SA">South Australia</option>
                <option value="TAS">Tasmania</option>
                <option value="VIC">Victoria</option>
                <option value="WA">Western Australia</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Postcode" maxlength="4" size="30" placeholder="Postcode">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Phone" maxlength="15" size="30" placeholder="Phone Number">
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Search">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</form>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: check what the filled in, add to query if info provided

Comment: And what would that look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **OR** condition requires that **any** of the conditions (ie: condition1, condition2, condition_n) be must be met for the record to be included in the result set.Whereas the  **AND** condition requires that **all** of the conditions (ie: condition1, condition2, condition_n) be must be met. For your requirement the **OR** condition is required.

You need to build a dynamic query to perform this. Start with a basic stub

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer";
```

Then you need to set the initial clause to  WHERE.

```
$clause = " WHERE ";//Initial clause
```

You need an array to store parameters

```
$paramArray =array();
```

Start building the query.Note I have changed from POST to GET as it is easier to test 
Also see [**PDO WIKI**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) for use % in placeholders.ie placeholders cannot represent an arbitrary part of the query, but a complete data literal only.

```
if(isset($_GET['First_name'])){
    $First_name = $_GET['First_name'];
    $sql .= "$clause First_name LIKE ?";
    $clause = " OR ";//Change clause
    array_push($paramArray,"%$First_name%");
}
```

Continue with next clause

```
if(isset($_GET['Surname'])){
    $Surname = $_GET['Surname'];
    $sql .= "$clause Surname LIKE ?";
    $clause = " OR ";
    array_push($paramArray,"%$Surname%");
}
```

Add remainder of clauses as above

Test result, Remove after testing & change GET to POST

```
echo $sql ;
echo "<br>";
print_r($paramArray);
```

Prepare and execute query

```
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($paramArray);
```

Typical Test Result from `test.php?First_name=dave&Surname=smith`

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE First_name LIKE ? OR Surname LIKE ?
Array ( [0] => %dave% [1] => %smith% )
```

from `test.php?Surname=smith`

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Surname LIKE ?
Array ( [0] => %smith% )
```

Answer (score -2):

Try changing

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE First_name LIKE '%$First_name%' OR Surname LIKE '%$Surname%' OR DOB LIKE '$DOB' OR Street LIKE '%$Street%' OR Suburb LIKE '$Suburb' OR State LIKE '$State' OR Postcode LIKE '$Postcode' OR Phone LIKE '$Phone'");
```

to

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE First_name LIKE '%'".$First_name."'%' OR ...
```

Take $First_name out of the literal string, and concatenate it with the literal string. What you were doing was literally searching for "$First_name", not the value of the $First_Name variable. It's a bit messy from an appearance perspective, but I have found it safer to concatenate text with variables rather than expand variables within quotes.

Darryl

Comment: Everything is wrong in this answer. It's not answering the question and is giving a wrong advice (the value of $First_name variable IS being used, since it's inside a double quote, not single). This might be a little old, but if a newbie stumbles upon this might get confused.