# PDO Query with variable number of queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm making a simple php page that is going to display information from a database, filtered by certain criteria. I would like to know if it's possible to have a PDO SQL query with a variable number of SQL 'where's.

If I was using mysql I would just do something like:

```
$condition1 = "WHERE male = 1 ";
$condition2 = "AND ethnicity = 1 ";
$condition3 = "";
$queryParam =  $condition1 . $condition2 . $condition3; 

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) from users '$queryParam'
```

Adding a new line for each condition

The query code doesn't need to be input from the code, I'm just trying to make the code easier to port for different projects.

Comment: Just remove those quotes as `"SELECT COUNT(*) from users $queryParam"`. Instead of making multiple variables you can simply use single variable `$condition = "WHERE male = 1 "; $condition .= "AND ethnicity = 1 ";` and `"SELECT COUNT(*) from users $condition"`

Comment: See my Answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097560/writing-a-query-that-contains-variable-where-based-on-user-input/27103625#27103625) you can change OR to AND depending on your needs.